# Element-UI el-select validation

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuejs2, element

I'm using Vue with Element-Ui and I'm having issues with the validation trigger on my `<el-select>` element. Essentially this is what the HTML looks like

```
<el-form-item label="Partner" prop="partner">    
  <el-select class="dialog-select" v-model="form.partner" placeholder="Partner">
      <el-option label="Zone one" value="shanghai"></el-option>
      <el-option label="Zone two" value="beijing"></el-option>
  </el-select>
</el-form-item>
```

and the JS validating the element looks like this

```
partner: [ { validator: validateInput, trigger: 'blur' } ]
```

My standard `<el-input>` validations are being triggered however. I have tried to change the trigger to `input`, `blur` as well as `focus` and neither of these events are firing. I cannot find any docs around what type of triggers their are either.

Edit: I have uploaded a fiddle with the issue. The validator will trigger onSubmit, however will also not clear once the rule should pass.

https://jsfiddle.net/k66a1gst/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct trigger for this element, it is the `change` trigger. The `change` trigger will also be required for things like dates. However it won't throw a validation error at you while tabbing past it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and also found that it looks like onBlur() isn't really supported, so I supplemented my onChange() validation rule with the following method:

```
<el-form ref="myForm">
    <el-form-item prop="fieldProp">
        <el-select @blur="validateDropdown"></el-select>
    </el-form-item>
</el-form>

validateDropdown() {
    this.$refs.myForm.validateField('fieldProp')
}
```

Wish it wasn't necessary, but it worked for me. Hope that helps someone!

Comment: I ran into some race conditions. I solved it by adding `debounce` to `validateDropdown()`